# Making BACK button to go to previous page in browser rather than previous activity

Tags: android, browser, back

I have an application that per user action to open a URL, opens a URL with ad and after a few seconds opens the URL requested by the user. Due to the need to run inside a Titanium module, I cannot open a webview, so I open the default browser (code below) twice. Once with the ad and once with the URL. Now, if the user wants to get back to the ad, he cannot do it with the BACK button as this one closes the browser and shows the previous activity. 
(this is the code:)

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Then, if one clicks on the BACK button he gets back to the previous activity. I would like to make the BACK button go to the previous browser URL. Is there a way to make it happen?

Thanks,
 Simon

Comment: explain the exact scenario..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set one tag on the intent and whenever you press back then check tag on back press button **OnBackPressed()** and write the webview.goBack() on back press

```
@override
public void OnBackPressed()
{
webview.goBack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want navigation in the webview to travel all the previous pages then you can put a back button and implement the navigation of the `webview` using the method `webview.goBack()`.

```
public void OnBackPressed()
{
your_webview.goBack().
}
```

Comment: Due to some constaints I open the default browser rather than a webview.

Comment: Then you can put the calling code inside OnBackPressed() as per your needs

Comment: Do you think my app will be called even though the default browser e.g. Chrome is opened on top of it?